# Calculate number of specific days in range

Tags: excel, date-arithmetic, dayofweek

How can I count the (fractional) count of specific day of the week in a range?  For instance, if the range is from Monday, June 3 12:00 P.M. to Tuesday June 4 12:00 P.M., and I want to count the number of Mondays, the formula would return the result 0.5.

I've already found a formula for the integer number of days:

`=SUM(INT((WEEKDAY($B2-x)+$D2-$B2)/7))`

where `x` is the day of the week of interest (1 to 7).  Of course, it would need to be modified to return the aforementioned result.  How would I do so?

Comment: You mean Tuesday June 4, right? ;)

Comment: Also, what should be the result if the range was from `Monday, 3 June 12:00 PM` to `Monday, June 10 12:00 PM`? Should it be `1` Monday?

Comment: @Jerry yes to both of your questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the total number of Mondays (including both start and end date) with this version (you don't need SUM)

`=INT((WEEKDAY($B2-2)+INT($D2)-INT($B2))/7)`

...and then do an adjustment to take into account the start/end days, e.g.

`=INT((WEEKDAY($B2-2)+INT($D2)-INT($B2))/7)-IF(WEEKDAY($D2)=2,1-MOD($D2,1))-IF(WEEKDAY($B2)=2,MOD($B2,1))`

I don't really recommend it (it's much more resource-hungry) but this version should give you the same result

`=SUMPRODUCT((TEXT(B2+(ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&ROUND((D2-B2)*1440,0)))-0.5)/1440,"ddd")="mon")+0)/1440`

It tests every minute within the date range to ascertain whether or not it falls on a Monday (assumes that you don't go down to seconds)

Comment: I don't understand what the second answer is supposed to get? IF you use sample data like from Monday, 3 June 12:00 PM to Monday, June 10 12:00 PM. The first formula returns 2, one for the starting Monday one for the ending Monday, while your second formula returns 1, is it returning the start or end Monday?

Comment: It's effectively returning 0.5 for the first Monday and 0.5 for the second - The first formula returns the total number of Mondays but it doesn't take account of the start or end times so the second version subtracts hours where the start or end date is a Monday.

Comment: I just simply fail to see how returning the 0.5 is useful.

Comment: The question says "How can I count the (fractional) count of specific day of the week in a range", so I'm assuming that Jeff wants to count exactly how many Mondays are in the range taking into account partial ones, e.g. if start time/date is 3 Jun 15:00 and end time/date is 3 Jun 21:00 the answer is 0.25 (all the range is on a Monday). If start is the same but end is Mon 24 June at 18:00 then that's 9 hours on start date, 2 whole Mondays then 18 hours on end date, 3.125 in all

Comment: @user2140261 get divorced and try to split up parenting time equally--then you'll understand.  :)

Comment: Something appears to be wrong with the second formula; entering a range of 6/24 12 PM to 6/30 10 AM results in a negative number when counting Sundays as `=SUM(INT((WEEKDAY($B6-1)+$D6-$B6)/7))-IF(WEEKDAY($D6)=1,1-MOD($D6,1))-IF(WEEKDAY($B6)=1,MOD($B6,1))`.  It also shows a negative number using 7/19 4pm to 7/26 12pm counting Fridays.

Comment: @Jeff_Axelrod That's a different formula from the one I posted - there needs to be INT functions around D6 and B6 in the first part of the formula (to take the date only from those date/time values). If you use the exact formula suggested you should get the expected results